Motor type require for robotic arm
I am making a tennis playing robot. There is a tennis racquet mounted on a robotic arm. I want suggestion on what kind of motor will better solve the purpose.
The arm consist of multiple motors but for now I only need suggestion for one as it would be similar for others. I have attached an image representing the setup below.

In the image below, the blue lines represent the path the racquet can move through. The green circle is the tennis ball.
Requirements:

The motor should have high precision. This is because the ball expected position is estimated and the racquet need to reach that point.
The motor should have high torque because it not only needs to lift the weight of the racquet but also hit the ball to deflect it otherwise the racquet will move backwards when it tries to hit ball having high speed.
The motor should have good if not high RPM as it would get 1-2 seconds to move in position.

I am confused between stepper and servo motor. Servos have high torque but very low RPM. Stepper also seems to be the same. Brushless DC motor have high RPM but I am not sure about their torque.
Also would taking a simple high RPM DC motor and attaching a gearbox(for torque) and an encoder solve the purpose?
Need views of others on this.
Thanks

From eyeballing it, I suspect you'll need a beefy motor or some gears in order to get enough torque, or a different design like a triangular string that pulls the top of the racquet sideways and the motor pulls the string. With a direct drive like shown in the picture, the holding torque is (very loosely speaking) the weight of the racquet, multiplied by the length of the racquet, divided by the length of the motor shaft; that is a big ratio that turns a medium amount of weight into a big amount of torque.

adding gears would likely increase the torque. Could you provide some more info on "triangular string that pulls the top of the racquet sideways".

like have a loop of string that ties onto the ratchet at the top, goes over a pulley far on the left side, goes past the motor, goes over a pulley far on the right side, and ties onto the ratchet again. But it's just an idea. I haven't worked out the design for you.

Maybe start with something that isn't potentially lethal to a human who is in the wrong place, then work up in power from that. Perhaps table tennis would be a good start. IMHO.
